# Javascript & PouchDB : can not return array of objects coming from pouchdb (because it is asynchronous?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, async-await, pouchdb

I'm using JS and PouchDB in a Cordova project. The structure of the PouchDB database is as follows:

```
var act = {
  _id: <some_id>,
  activity: <some_description>,
  totaltime: <string_represeting_duration>,
  instances: [{datum: "04/04/18", tijd: "01:10"},{datum: "04/04/18", tijd: "00:35"}]
};
```

I have a function that should return an array of objects, namely from the field instances:

```
function queryDbForDatesAndDuration(todo) {
    var objDandD = [];

    db.get(todo._id).then(function(doc) {
        var t = doc.instances.length;
        for(i=0; i<t; i++) {
            objDandD[i] = {
                datum: doc.instances.datum,
                tijd: doc.instances.tijd
            };
        }
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(objDandD);
        return objDandD;
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log("And error occured while querying the DB for date and duration: " + err);
    });
}
```

The query to the database works, but ObjDandD is not passed when returned. I first thought that this is because PouchDB works asynchronous and the value is not resolved when returned, but using async / await did not help :

```
async function createSingleAct(todo) {
    ...
    var Ob = await queryDbForDatesAndDuration(todo);
    ...
```

It just keeps giving a TypeError :

```
TypeError: Ob is undefined
```

Anyone can help me with this? I've been searching desperately without result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `queryDbForDatesAndDuration` doesn't actually return anything. So while the db call works ok, and your `objDandD` object does get set, that's as far as it goes. In order for this to work, you could return the promise generated by `db.get`. For example:

```
function queryDbForDatesAndDuration(todo) {
  var objDandD = [];

  return db.get(todo._id).then(function(doc) {
    var t = doc.instances.length;
    ...
```

But this also makes `queryDbForDatesAndDuration` an async function, so the caller will need to use `.then()` to access the result. For example:

```
queryDbForDatesAndDuration(someTodo).then(objDandD => {
  // do something with objDandD here
})
```

Or, as you have in your question, `await` should work as well.